# How to migrate old Flutter project to dart 3

Tags: flutter, dart

How to migrate old Flutter project to dart 3 with latest Flutter version.

My project works with following:
Flutter version: 3.7.12
sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"

When I upgrade Flutter to latest version so I need to migrate the whole project to be compatible with Dart 3 with null safety...
It's not easy to change the code (like variablers) manually in over 100 files.

Is there any way to migrate a Flutter project and change everything required to run dart 3 using commands in Terminal?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dart migrate` command in dart 2.19

if you want use dart 2.19, use Flutter 3.7.12 with `flutter downgrade 3.7.12` command.

For more information, read [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/50319)

Comment: I already have Flutter 3.7.12 with sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0" do you that I need to upgrade sdk to ">=2.19.0 <3.0.0" and run dart migrate? thanks

Comment: first, migrate to null safety code with `dart migrate` command, and upgrade flutter to 3.10 @blue492

Answer (score 1):

Rather than downgrade flutter to ruin your main installation (although temporarily), consider using [Puro](https://puro.dev) instead, to maintain multiple versions of flutter at the same time.  I have [a nice video on that](https://youtu.be/olqmK-opexA).

Comment: Randal, I used `fvm` before but have to say that `puro` is far better, do you by any chance know what `--global` switch means in `puro use` command?

Comment: is it simply used for changing `~/.puro/envs/default` symbolic link?